# Missing classes in google-cloud:0.18.0-alpha

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I updated google-cloud dependency from `0.4.0` to `0.18.0-alpha`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.18.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
```

After version update, following classes are gone.

```
com.google.cloud.AuthCredentials
com.google.cloud.Page
```

Which classes should I replace them with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `com.google.api.gax.paging.Page` instead of `com.google.cloud.Page`

Use `com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials` instead of `com.google.cloud.AuthCredentials`.

`AuthCredentials.ServiceAccountAuthCredentials`class is removed (see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/1375).

**Old usage**

```
AuthCredentials.ServiceAccountAuthCredentials serviceAccountAuthCredentials = AuthCredentials
            .ServiceAccountAuthCredentials.createForJson(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE));
```

**New usage**

```
ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountAuthCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE));
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/pull/1947

**Some methods are renamed**

- builder() methods renamed to newBuilder()
- getter/setter methods renamed to Java Bean naming standard. For example, `BlobId.bucket()` renamed to `BlobId.getBucket()`.